# iOS: app will not open without cordova-plugin-file-transfer

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-file

Im using cordova for my iOS app, but wont open in my simulator. Is there a work around this, has this issue been updated?

[image: build failed with one error code]

Comment: On its own, Cordova/ios doesn't need the cordova-plugin-file-transfer plugin (and should work in the simulator w/o compile time builds). Can you provide some more info? Are you using the file transfer plugin in your app? Have you tried `cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-file-transfer` / `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer` to reinstall the plugin?

Comment: Yes I did, but unfortunately the app doesnt build succesfully, it does without the plugin, but the app doesnt fully ope, im gessing some callback functions wont work without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple things to look at in order to track the issue down:

- If you're wanting to use the file transfer plugin and just get the build to complete successfully, check to see what version of the plugin you're using. From what I can tell on the github page for the plugin (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer), the CI build has been broken for a while (see https://travis-ci.com/github/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/builds). It's possible that you got a bad build at some point. It looks like 1.7.1 (the last release) built successfully, so you might want to try deleting *again* and re-adding the 1.7.1 version specifically:

  `cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-file-transfer`

  `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer@1.7.1`
- If you're wanting to take the file transfer plugin out of the app and get the app running that way, you probably need to launch the app and use Safari's developer tools to pull out the exception that's being thrown on startup. Alternately, you can do a find in files for references to the `FileTransfer` / `FileUploadOptions` / `FileUploadResult` and comment them out.